# JavaScript string (and a seed), and create a non-cryptographic 64-bit hash from it

Tags: javascript, angular, hash, javascript-objects

Having a string and a seel i would like to get a hash of 64-bits in number format

I have use murmurhash but it return 32bits.

this is what i was doing:

```
var seel =123456'
var hash = murmurhash(name,seel)
```

I am trying this but it return a word, not a number

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA512(name ,seel );
```

Is there any way of return a string only composed by number?
something like 65489632455865, as this will be like 64-bits number

Comment: Javascript doesn't have a 64-bit integer type.

Comment: Does anybody know what a 'seel' is in this context? Maybe a 'seed'?

Answer (score 1):

As commented, the Javascript Number type is a general purpose value based on the [IEEE 754 standard](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ieee-standard-754-floating-point-numbers/) for a double precision number.  Since the format reserves 12 bits for the sign and exponent values, The largest integer that can be represented safely is 2<sup>53</sup>-1, and represented by the [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) constant.

Most browsers have support for [the BigInt type](https://caniuse.com/?search=bigint) now so that might be an option for you, although it is far from clear as to why you need this hash or what you plan to do with it.

You might also take a look at this [js Siphash](https://github.com/jedisct1/siphash-js) implementation.  In comparison to murmurhash, it has better protection against collisions, and can be used by breaking up a 64 bit Siphash into 2 32 bit integers, so that might be an option for you without using a [Bigint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt).